# Справочник из xsd файла

Tags: c#

Есть xsd файл состоящий из нескольких сотен узлов вида:

```
    <xs:enumeration value="1">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>информация</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:enumeration>
```

Мне по значению атрибута `value` необходимо получать "информацию" из тега `<xs:documentation>`. Как наиболее оптимально по вашему мнению это сделать? Загрузить в `XmlDocument()` и с помощью `XPatch` или `Linq` искать узел и получать значение? Или сразу распарсить в массив или словарь и работать с ним?

Comment: Вам надо "получать" информацию при разборе XML-документа или для других целей?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Для разбора, те обращение к xsd будет частым

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое что можно сделать - это загрузить его **в словарь**:

```
XNamespace xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
var type = XDocument.Load(...).Descendants(xs + "simpleType")
  .Single(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "...");
var dict = type.Descendants(xs + enumeration).ToDictionary(
  x => (string)x.Attribute("value"),
  x => (string)x.Element(xs + "annotation").Element(xs + "documentation")
);
```

Comment: Интересный способ, спасибо буду разбираться